# Count the quantity of unique combinations of multiple columns in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have two columns in a spreadsheet, and I need to write a formula to determine how many times each combination shows up. Example:

```
A  1
A  1
A  2
A  2
A  2
B  1
B  1
B  2
```

Should result in:

```
A  1  2
A  2  3
B  1  2
B  2  1
```

I did it very easily yesterday by importing into a SQL table, but I need to make it so anyone can do it, simply by placing those two columns in a spreadsheet. It should then populate a second sheet with the quantities table.

Comment: In the first set of example data should there be a `3` somewhere? Where did the `3` in the results come from?

Comment: Additionally you ask if you can find `how many times each combination shows up` but the example results show all the results. Would you like a single number representing all the possible combinations of would you like to see those combinations?

Comment: @Brad - The 3 is because the combination `A  2` shows up three times.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Edit:**  *Simple solution  (credit goes to SaintWacko)*

Concatenate the two columns:

```
=$A2&$B2
```

Create a pivot table, using the concatenated column as a 'Row Label' and a 'Value'.  Then make sure the 'Value' is calculating counts (should be default).

*Complicated solution*

You can concatenate the two columns in column C:

```
=$A2&$B2
```

In column D, you'll need a function that determines if the item is a duplicate of another item so that the value is true for only one of each item (this only works if the items are sorted by the data columns, but the macro later does that).

```
=$C1<>$C2
```

Then calculate the count if matched in column E:

```
=COUNTIF($C:$C,$C2)
```

A macro will find all combinations for you, place them on sheet 2 and copy the counts.  The code below makes some assumptions, but you can probably modify it to do what you need.

```
Option Explicit

Sub GetCombinations()

    Dim sheet1, sheet2 As Worksheet
    Set sheet1 = Worksheets(1)
    Set sheet2 = Worksheets(2)

    Dim sStartColumn As String
    Dim iTopRow As Long
    Dim sEndColumn As String
    Dim iBottomRow As Long

    sStartColumn = "A"
    iTopRow = 1
    sEndColumn = "E"
    iBottomRow = sheet1.UsedRange.Rows.Count

    Dim Rng As Range
    Dim sRange1 As String
    sRange1 = sStartColumn & CStr(iTopRow) & ":" & sEndColumn & CStr(iBottomRow)

    Set Rng = sheet1.Range(sRange1)

    Rng.Sort Key1:=Range("A2"), Order1:=xlAscending, _
             Key2:=Range("B2"), Order2:=xlAscending, _
             Orientation:=xlSortColumns, Header:=xlYes

    Dim i, j As Integer

    j = 2

    For i = 2 To iBottomRow

        If sheet1.Cells(i, 4) Then

            sheet2.Cells(j, 1) = sheet1.Cells(i, 1)
            sheet2.Cells(j, 2) = sheet1.Cells(i, 2)
            sheet2.Cells(j, 3) = sheet1.Cells(i, 5)
            j = j + 1

        End If

    Next i

End Sub
```

That should do it.

Comment: I would be happy with a macro to do it. I can't list out every combination, though. A, B, 1, 2, was just a greatly simplified example. It's actually combinations of zip codes and carrier routes.

Comment: okay... give me a bit.  I'll edit my answer

Comment: You may have something there with that concatenation, however. I can count the quantity of each unique value for a single column. Then the only problem is selecting only a single entry for each unique value.

Comment: Why do you need a list of all the combinations? Why not just search for how many times each combination appears?

Comment: Another sheet in the spreadsheet generates some sort of tag that gets printed out and used in shipping. I don't know the exact details, someone else wrote the code that generates the tag. I just need to be able to supply a sheet with three columns: Zip code, Carrier route, and the quantitiy of each combination of the two.

Comment: @SaintWacko I've updated the answer with the macro for you...

Comment: Alright, I'll see if I can work that out. I haven't ever used a macro before. I really don't work with excel that much. Also, I just noticed your avatar. The A-10 has always been my favorite aircraft :)

Comment: It _is_ a mean beast!

Comment: Hm, I get an overflow on this line: `iBottomRow = sheet1.UsedRange.Rows.Count` Erm, perhaps I should have mentioned that it's over 44k rows.

Comment: The iBottomRow is an integer.  Change it to long  Find the line Dim iBottomRow as Integer and change it to a Dim iBottomRow as Long.

This sounds to me like a good use of a pivot table

Comment: Heh, I think I actually just figured out how to do it using a pivot table, combined with gregsdennis's suggestion to concatenate.

Comment: The Integer type is probably 16-bit giving a max value of 32,767.  Try running again changing Integer to Long (see above edit)

Comment: yeah, I guess a pivot table would also work.  Just use 'concat' and 'Count of Combo'

Comment: Yep, that's exactly what I did. Then I used 'LEFT' and 'RIGHT' to separate it back out into the two columns (fortunately, each column is always the same length).